# Bind data to MS Dynamics CRM sub grid from external database

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am not able to set lookup fields on MSCRM sub grid from external database.

I tried with the retrieve multiple plugin as:

get the data from external database in datatable

```
EntityCollection entityCollection= (EntityCollection)context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntityCollection"];
Entity anyEntity= new Entity("entity");

anyEntity.Attributes["new_customerid"] = new EntityReference("contact", new Guid("B26EF3E7-BD68-E411-9447-00155D010B06"));
anyEntity.Attributes["new_address1"] ="value from datatable";

entityCollection.Entities.Add(anyEntity);
```

Except lookup type field I am able to bind all the fields to the sub grid from external database.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected since you cannot "look up" to a record in a different database.  CRM enforces foreign key constraints on lookup fields so that you can only set a lookup value to point to an entity that actually exists in that CRM system.  You could however set the lookup to a value in CRM based on some value in the other database.

Comment: I am trying to display external database values in ms crm sub grid, 
In a grid some columns are free text field and few columns are of lookup fields.
I am able to set values to columns having free text field in ms crm but not able to set values to lookup type field in retrieve multiple plugin.

for eg. Customer having client id 12345678 in external database and in ms crm also, in this case when I tried to set lookup for the client in the retrievemultiple plugin it shows blank value for lookup type field in subgrid.

Comment: It doesn't look like you read my answer.  You can of course set non-lookup values from another database.  A lookup field however is a reference to a record in a table.  You can only reference records that exist in tables in your CRM database which means that you cannot set a lookup to point to a record in a foreign database.

Comment: I am querying the data from crm database to set lookup in retrievemultiple plugin to display data in sub grid, based on the values retrieved from external database.
eg.external database has mobileno, emailid and client id - 9890124560 a@a.com 123456874
ms crm contact has client id and guid - 123456874 463463A3-C5CE-E311-9427-00155D010B06 , 
code: 
Entity contact=new Entity("contact");
contact["contactid"]=new EntityReference("contact", new Guid("123456874 463463A3-C5CE-E311-9427-00155D010B06")); 
contact["mobilenumber"]="mobile number from external database";
contact["emailid"]="from ext db";